# Preserve the hidden or visible state of initially hidden textbox on postback in mvc application

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Given below is my script.My problem is I have a textbox which is hidden and is diplayed only when we select "other" from dropdownlist.On display when we enter a value after post back that value gets preserved but that textbox becomes invisible.on postback dropdown list value is however preserved and shown as "others" and only when I select someother value of dropdown and then again change it to "other" then textbox along with text gets displayed..how can I preserve that hidden or visible state of it on postback?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#SelectedCategoryId').change(function () {
      if ($('#SelectedCategoryId').val() === '5') {
        $('#other').show(1000);
        $('#other').change(function () {
          var SelectedCategory = $('#other').val().toString();
          $('#hiddenId').val(SelectedCategory);
        });
      }
      else {
        $('#other').hide(1000);
        var SelectedCategory = $('#SelectedCategoryId option:selected').text();
        $('#hiddenId').val(SelectedCategory);
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

My View

```
<div id="dropdown" class="form-control dropdown">
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedCategoryId, "*")
 @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Category, "Department :", new { style = "display:inline;" })
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCategoryId, new SelectList(Model.Category, "Value", "Text"), "SelectCategory", new { id = "SelectedCategoryId"})
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Other, "*")
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Other, new { id = "other", @class = "other" ,style = "display: none;" })              
 @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SelectedCategory, new { id = "hiddenId" })
</div>
```

Comment: Tip: You should get introduced to `$(this)` and `this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's becaue you only check for the value of the select on "change" event. That doesn't happen when you load the page. Do it like that:

```
function toggleHidden() { //that's your code in a function
    if ($('#SelectedCategoryId').val() === '5') {
        $('#other').show(1000);
        $('#other').change(function () {
            var SelectedCategory = $('#other').val().toString();
            $('#hiddenId').val(SelectedCategory);
        });
    }
    else {
        $('#other').hide(1000);
        var SelectedCategory = $('#SelectedCategoryId option:selected').text();
        $('#hiddenId').val(SelectedCategory);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    toggleHidden(); //execute the toggle on load
    $('#SelectedCategoryId').change(toggleHidden); //execute the toggle on change
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort.you made me clear of where I went wrong.. :)